# Docker & .Net: The command could not be loaded while dotnet and dll file are present

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

After successfully building my `Dockerfile`, the Asp.Net Core application will not start using `docker-compose up`.

I get the following output when starting the container:

```
daemon         | The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
daemon         |   * You intended to execute a .NET application:
daemon         |       The application 'Daemon.dll' does not exist.
daemon         |   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
daemon         |       No .NET SDKs were found.
daemon         | 
daemon         | Download a .NET SDK:
daemon         | https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
daemon         | 
daemon         | Learn about SDK resolution:
daemon         | https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
daemon exited with code 145
```

This would indicate that my problem would be that either dotnet is not present in the container, however, if I run the following set of commands this is what happens:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash daemon
root@6ceeca7bedb1:/app# dotnet Daemon.dll
[2022-11-09 22:19:42.290 +00:00  INF]  Now listening on: http://[::]:7267
[2022-11-09 22:19:42.337 +00:00  INF]  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[2022-11-09 22:19:42.338 +00:00  INF]  Hosting environment: Production
[2022-11-09 22:19:42.338 +00:00  INF]  Content root path: /app/
```

I interpret this result as though both dotnet and the required dll file are present.

I'll paste the contents of the `Dockerfile` below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 7267

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:7267

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["./*.sln", "./"]
COPY ["./Daemon/Daemon.csproj", "./Daemon/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./Daemon/Daemon.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Daemon"
RUN dotnet build "Daemon.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Daemon.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Daemon.dll"]
```

And here's the content of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  daemon:
    container_name: 'daemon'
    hostname: 'daemon'
    image: 'daemon'
    ports:
      - '7267:7267/tcp'
    networks:
      database:
      authentication:
    volumes:
      - './Daemon:/app'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: './Daemon/Dockerfile'
    entrypoint: ['dotnet', 'Daemon.dll']
```

What is it that I'm missing here? I've been fixating on this problem for the last couple of hours but I can't seem to find the cause.

EDIT:
I've removed `entrypoint: ['dotnet', 'Daemon.dll']` from the `docker-compose.yml` and changed `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Daemon.dll"]` in the `Dockerfile`to each of the following and none of those work either:

- `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/Daemon.dll"]`
- `ENTRYPOINT "dotnet Daemon.dll"`
- `ENTRYPOINT "dotnet /app/Daemon.dll"`
- `CMD ["dotnet", "Daemon.dll"]`
- `CMD ["dotnet", "/app/Daemon.dll"]`
- `CMD "dotnet Daemon.dll"`
- `CMD "dotnet /app/Daemon.dll"`

Comment: In Linux, the file system is case-sensitive, so make sure the casing is right in the file name. In cases like this, it's useful to run an interactive shell in the container to explore the filesystem and run commands to determine what's wrong. I would suggest building the Dockerfile locally and running it with `docker run --rm -it <image-name>`. Then run `ls` to see the files that exist in the app directory.

Comment: @MattThalman Thanks for your reply. I have checked the casing by running the application from within the docker container itself, which works. Casing is not the issue here, as I've shown in my question.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I could solve this issue through adding my service to the launchSettings.json in docker-compose project. This was missing because I added this project manually to the VS solution and to docker compose.

```
{ 
  "profiles": {
    "Docker Compose": {
      "commandName": "DockerCompose",
      "commandVersion": "1.0",
      "serviceActions": {
        "<service name>": "StartDebugging" //<<--- here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compose file is overriding the `/app` folder with your local `Daemon` folder which from what I'm seeing is the project's source folder, not the published app. If so, removing the volume mount should resolve the issue.